# Display GET Value Inside Of On Bodyload Command

Tags: php, onload

This is what Ive come up with, but I'm not sure what else I need to do for it.

```
<body onload=window.location='<?php " . $_GET["u"] . " ?>'>
```

Comment: Please remember to be more descriptive. E.g. giving us the error you got.

Comment: @FluffyJack It ain't valid PHP. It's very easy to see the problem here.

Comment: Just for his reference in the future :)

Comment: There wasn't an error message, it was simply just a stupid mistake, but if I didn't ask here it probably would of taken me hours to actually notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `echo` and wrote extra `"`s:

```
<body onload=window.location='<?php echo $_GET["u"]; ?>'>
```

Be aware that any input you receive from `GET` or `POST` should first be sanitised.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo it out:

```
<?php echo $_GET["u"]; ?>
```

Why do you need to do this? This will make your website vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: Nothing is stored in my website, people can feel free to hack it and steal every file stored in it. They aren't going to get too much.

Comment: it aint about stealing things from your website .. think what could happen if i hack any other  website using your website... sounds trouble for you isnt it ?